# Access SQL Avoid Cartesian Product using Instr = 0 or Not Like

Tags: sql, ms-access, cartesian-product

I have two tables

```
T1        T2
list      remark
abc       this is my list  
def       i have abc remark 
ghi       other than I have def comment
jkl       ghi is also there
          and this one will
          and this one too
```

I am attempting to write a query that will return all remarks in T2 that are not like the list in T1.

I have tried both `Instr` and Join with `Not Like`, but am stuck on the Cartesian Product issue.

Running a query where Instr = True returns the list I expect

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.remark, InStr([t2].[remark],[t1].[list]) AS [Check]
FROM t2, t1
WHERE (((InStr([t2].[remark],[t1].[list]))=True));
```

> ghi is also there
>   I have abc remark
>   other than I have def comment

But running for False is where I get all results, due to Cartesian Product:

Same with using `Not Like`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.remark
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.Remark NOT LIKE "*" & t1.List & "*"
```

I have also tried sub queries, but no luck. Any idea how I can solve this with Access SQL?

I suppose I could write the statement with TRUE then do another query where the remarks do not equal the result of my first query, but that seems a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way (at least in Access) is like this:

```
SELECT tr.remark
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 
  ON t2.Remark LIKE "*" & t1.List & "*"
WHERE t1.List IS NULL
```

although I'm not sure if I have ever used this with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

@Andre beat me by a few minutes.

This also appears to work and returns 3 records

```
SELECT  remark
        , list
FROM    T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON INSTR(T2.remark,T1.list)>0
```

1. I have abc remark / abc
2. other than I have def comment / def
3. ghi is also there / ghi

**Sorry... that returns the opposite.**

Use:

```
SELECT  remark
        , list
FROM    T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON INSTR(T2.remark,T1.list)>0
WHERE   list IS NULL
```

1. this is my list / NULL
2. and this one will / NULL
3. and this one too / NULL

Comment: I like that I tried both `Instr` and `Like` and got answers for both :)